# Javascript Array find Object or tuple

Tags: javascript, arrays, tuples, associative-array

I am building a movement logic for some "elements" on a map.
I have the tiles defined by their X and Y position and now I need to assign an element to a tile. 
In generic terms I want to do something like this: [0,1] => ElementX, and then store this into "something".

However with JavaScript arrays I cannot do "something".indexOf either of [0,1] or ElementX (its an object) or event ElementXId.

So what I ended up doing is this:

```
TileVector["" + x + y] = [x,y] //translates to TileVector["6060"] = [60,60]
```

and

```
TileElementVector["" + x + y] = ElementX;
```

Now when I want to see what is on a specific coordinate I just string the x and y coordinates.

I am just wondering how bad or how slow is this and if there are other solutions.

Thank you.

I will elaborate a bit as to how this is being used.
A map of 200 by 200 is created, which contains tiles of 1px. In order to map every tile to a specific id (for quick access) I am creating a array like this: TileVector[""+x+y] = [x+y] *as pointed out this is not bulletproof*

Now when an Element is placed on the map, I need to associate that element with that position on the map thus [x+y] => Element and store it in a whole new array.

Comment: How do you know if `TileVector["6060"]` is `[606,0]` or `[60,60]`? You should go for a Two-dimensional array.

Comment: the only "problem" I have is that I want TileVector and TileElementVector to be separated and also keep TileElementVector small. If I make the TileVector 2d then I will not be able to say TileElementVector[x][y] = Element because I need to initialise the TileElementVector with all the possible values. You can't out of the blue put a 2d value to it.

Comment: also an easy dummy way to fix the issue you mentioned is to add the comma. so 60,60 = "60,60" and 60,6 = "60,6"

Comment: All those int to string conversions are going to be kind of expensive I would expect. You're better off using the "x * maxX + y" approach and stay with integer indexes.

Comment: i will give it a go with the maxX etc. thnx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with the following?

```
TileElementVector[x][y]
```

You will have to initialize both dimensions of the array like so:

```
TileElementVector = [];
for (var i = 0; i < maxY; i++){
  TileElementVector[i] = [];
}
```

where `maxY` is simply the maximum value that Y can take on in this hypothetical 2-D grid.
In terms of speed, none of this is a real issue. But if you **really** want to store the array one-dimensionally, you can use this neat math trick:

```
TileElementVector[x * maxY + y]
```

This will ensure that each element gets a unique index. This is essentially "flattening" the array. However, since this is a bit trickier to use, I recommend the first solution.

Comment: the thing is that the TileElementVector is never initialised with values. of course I could, but it would just create another "big" array. The TileVector will contain all the tiles, because in the future they might be used by other things expect the elementVector. So the moment I add an element at 60,60 I need to immediately say TileElementVector at 60,60 = Element thus I cannot do TileElementVector[60][60]. could you elaborate more on the maxY ?

Comment: Do you want a sparse representation in memory? This is geared towards a 2-dimensional array...

Answer (score 0):

```
function toIndex(x, y, rowSize) {
    return y * rowSize + x;
}

function fromIndex(idx, rowSize) {
    return {
        x: idx % rowSize,
        y: Math.floor(idx / rowSize)
    };
}

var colSize, rowSize;
var TileElementVector = new Array(colSize * rowSize);

var tileIdx = toIndex(xTile, yTile, rowSize);
var coords = fromIndex(tileIdx, rowSize);
coords.x == xTile && coords.y == yTile;
```